# What does 덩그러니 mean in the sentence 또 덩그러니 내게 남겨져있어?

Tags: meaning, transliteration

I'm searching for the meaning of 덩그러니 word as I'm not able to find any correct meaning for this word. So can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

The adverv '덩그러니' describes that something is left in a big and hollow space. I don't know your context, but it seems that '또 덩그러니 내게 남겨져 있어?' implies that something which might mean some task(?) is left behind to the subject (내게) again without anybody's help.

Answer (score 0):

덩그러니 can be 1) (of an object or person) in a stark and conspicuous manner (because it is all by itself or doesn't go along with the surroundings), or 2) (of a place) looking or feeling overly large and sparse so as to give an impression of desolation.

There doesn't seem to be a close match in English, but I think "starkly" for sense-1, and "desolately" for sense-2 can convey similar idea.

The following lines from the Doors song *Riders on the Storm* might give you an idea.  The original lyrics don't include a word like 덩그러니, but it seems like a perfect place to add it if you're translating it to Korean.

```
Into this world we're thrown                     우린 이 세상에 덩그러니 던져져
Like a dog without a bone, an actor out on loan  뼈다귀 찾는 개처럼, 배역을 잃어버린 배우처럼
```